# Tribute band logo copyright infringement

Tags: logo, copyright, legal

My band created this logo as an idea for our tribute band to the Beatles:

[image]

Since it is based on the original Beatles logo:

[image]

Would the logo be considered copyright infringement?

We know the name itself is OK to use, but are not sure about the font or anything else.

Comment: I made some edits and reopened your question, feel free to edit more if my edits changed too much (You could do with adding some more details e.g. on where/how the logo will be used)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a legal issue

Answer (score 2):

The fonts usage is subject t its own copyright issues. If you bought the font its fine to use it. If the font is protected private property then it is not. If this font is very similiar to an existing font then copyright is left up to the lawyers

The Beatles artwork is copyrighted.

Do they infringe on the Beatles brand? That is a legal question with no Yes or No answer until the lawyers decide.

I think a general legal approach/strategy is a good idea. "Yes, the font and design were taken from the Beatles brand. We have changed it enough that no one would mistake this for the Beatles own work. It is a tribute to them, we are a tribute to them." If it enters a legal battle than I think the first step would be an order for you to stop using it. That sounds not so bad to me.

Comment: Is it due to the Font? We know the name itself is fine.

Comment: The fonts usage is subject t its own copyright issues. If you bought the font its fine to use it. If the font is protected  private property then it is not. If this font is very similiar to an existing font then copyright is left up to the lawyers.

Comment: The font was from a free download. I have not found anything saying it's illegal to use. I understand what you are saying and it's much appreciated. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: In your opinion, if we lose the iconic "drop T", do you think we'd be in the clear?

Comment: I think a general legal approach/strategy  is a good idea. "Yes, the font and design were taken from the Beatles brand. We have changed it enough that no one would mistake this for the Beatles own work. It is a tribute to them, we are a tribute to them." If it enters a legal battle than I think the first step would be an order for you to stop using it. That sounds not so bad to me.

Comment: @Webster You should probably include some of those comments in your answer